# Series expansion of the absolute value of complex variables

Tags: taylor-expansion, physics, nonlinear-system, linearization

Consider the function $f(u)=|u|^{2k}$ where $u$ is a complex number, and $k$ is an integer. I need to 'linearize' this equation* around the value $\phi$. In other words I need a series expansion of $f(\phi + r)$ where $\phi$ and $r$ are complex, and $r$ is small. I would appreciate either solutions or suggestions on the correct approach to this problem or literature references.

[*] I ask this question because I am a physicist learning about linear stability of stationary solutions of nonlinear differential equations; and I am trying to follow example 2 on [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_stability) Wikipedia page, and I am not confident about how series expansions work for functions that involve absolute values of complex numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's easier if you forget about the fact that you're working with complex numbers and instead pretend you're just in $\mathbb R^2$. Then the linearization of $f$ at $\vec x_0$ is simply $f(\vec x_0+\vec h)\approx f(\vec x_0)+\nabla f(\vec x_0)\cdot \vec h$. Rename $x_0$ and $h$ to your liking.